# Is $.000\dots001$ equal to $0$?

Tags: inequality, real-numbers, infinitesimals

I am not particularly formally educated in maths. I have just learned that $.999\dots=1$, so it feels somewhat natural to me that $.000\dots1 = 0$. Is this the case?

Comment: First you'd have to describe what "$.000\ldots1$ is. While a decimal can have infinitely many decimal places, there is no 'last place'. What one can say, however, is that if $x_n = 0.\underbrace{0\ldots0}_\text{$n$ times}1$, then the limit of the sequence $x_0,x_1,x_2,\ldots$ is equal to $0$.

Comment: If your one is $n$ places after the decimal point, then it equals $1/10^n$ and this is $>0$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$.

Comment: You need to define "$.000\ldots 1$".

Comment: This makes no sense, we cannot have infinite many zeros followed by a $1$

Answer (score 6):

Nice question. In fact, there is no such real number as $.000 \ldots 1$.

The digits in a decimal expansion -- even an infinite one -- are ordered by the natural numbers, so it makes sense to speak of the first digit, the second digit, and so on, after the decimal point. The string of symbols $.000 \ldots 1$ is not a decimal expansion, because there is no answer to "which digit is $1$"?

Comment: another way to say it: for any number $n$, if I ask you: what's the $n$th digit of your number after the decimal point, you will tell me $0$. And so my queries can't distinguish your number from "zero." You are probably thinking "but I am imagining a string of infinitely many zeroes, then a one after." That's a perfectly coherent string of symbols, but it doesn't represent a number.

Comment: How does one represent an infinitesimally small number? Or is that simply what zero is?

Comment: "How does one represent an infinitesimally small number?" The ordinary real numbers don't have such a thing, but there are systems of "hyperreal numbers" which do. In them, the answer to your question is "not with an "infinite decimal" like yours".